# Flutter completely broken after update (again)

Tags: flutter

TL;DR VERSION:

Have a bunch of apps I work on regularly, some of which are published to the app store.   Recently updated flutter and android studio and now everything is completely broken to the point none of my apps will even run any more.

LONG VERSION:

I have been working on this problem full time for this entire week, without any success so far.  I have tried countless suggestions of people having similar issues in forums, I have done everything suggested to me in any discussion threads.  I have made progress of a kind, because whereas previously even the base vanilla application you are given when you create a new project would die when you add any plugins to it, I have got past this now to my latest issue:

At the moment it seems to try and run an application to my device, the application seems to build successfully and run, but immediately closes on the phone.   There is no error as such but these are the latest lines from flutter run -v:

```
                 E: meta-data (line=181)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.gms.version" (Raw: "com.google.android.gms.version")
                   A: android:value(0x01010024)=@0x7f060001
[  +13 ms] Stopping app 'app.apk' on SM G970F.
[  +23 ms] executing: C:\Installations\AndroidSDK\platform-tools\adb.exe -s RF8M33L3WLK shell am force-stop app.appname
[ +120 ms] executing: C:\Installations\AndroidSDK\platform-tools\adb.exe -s RF8M33L3WLK shell pm list packages app.appname
[ +222 ms] Installing APK.
[   +4 ms] executing: C:\Installations\AndroidSDK\platform-tools\adb.exe version
[  +60 ms] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
           Version 29.0.4-5871666
           Installed as C:\Installations\AndroidSDK\platform-tools\adb.exe
[   +2 ms] executing: C:\Installations\AndroidSDK\platform-tools\adb.exe start-server
[  +41 ms] Installing android\build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk...
[   +1 ms] executing: C:\Installations\AndroidSDK\platform-tools\adb.exe -s RF8M33L3WLK install -t -r C:\Projects\Apps\app.appname\android\build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk
[+23392 ms] Performing Streamed Install
                     Success
[   +2 ms] Installing android\build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk... (completed in 23.4s)
[   +6 ms] executing: C:\Installations\AndroidSDK\platform-tools\adb.exe -s RF8M33L3WLK shell echo -n 0d4daf35397951507aa469d3eecceb6e826a3f62 > /data/local/tmp/sky.app.appname.sha1
[  +88 ms] SM G970F startApp
[   +3 ms] executing: C:\Installations\AndroidSDK\platform-tools\adb.exe -s RF8M33L3WLK shell am start -a android.intent.action.RUN -f 0x20000000 --ez enable-background-compilation true --ez
enable-dart-profiling true --ez enable-checked-mode true --ez verify-entry-points true app.appname/app.appname.MainActivity
[ +125 ms] Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.RUN flg=0x20000000 cmp=app.appname/.MainActivity (has extras) }
[   +1 ms] Waiting for observatory port to be available...
```

The application seems to crash the same instant the last line (waiting for observatory port) appears.  Not sure what I should be looking into here, or where it might be falling over.

EDIT:

Flutter doctor -v output:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.10.7, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.805], locale en-AU)
    • Flutter version 1.10.7 at c:\flutter
    • Framework revision e70236e36c (2 weeks ago), 2019-10-02 09:32:30 -0700
    • Engine revision 9e6314d348
    • Dart version 2.6.0 (build 2.6.0-dev.4.0 1103600280)


[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Installations\AndroidSDK\
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Installations\AndroidSDK\
    • Java binary at: C:\Installations\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at C:\Installations\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 40.2.2
    • Dart plugin version 191.8580
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • SM G970F • [xxxxx] • android-arm64 • Android 9 (API 28)

• No issues found!
```

EDIT2:

Stacktrace results, as requested:

```
gradlew build --stacktrace
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details

> Configure project :app
WARNING: API 'variant.getMergeResources()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getMergeResourcesProvider()'.
It will be removed at the end of 2019.
For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
To determine what is calling variant.getMergeResources(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display a stack trace.

> Task :firebase_admob:compileProfileJavaWithJavac
Note: C:\Users\riley\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_admob-0.9.0+7\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebaseadmob\AdRequestBuilderFactory.java uses or overrides a deprecated A
PI.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

> Task :in_app_purchase:compileProfileJavaWithJavac
Note: C:\Users\riley\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\in_app_purchase-0.2.1+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\inapppurchase\InAppPurchasePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations
.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

> Task :url_launcher:compileProfileJavaWithJavac
Note: C:\Users\riley\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\url_launcher-5.1.6\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\urllauncher\WebViewActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

> Task :vibration:compileProfileJavaWithJavac
Note: C:\Users\riley\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\vibration-1.2.1\android\src\main\java\com\benjaminabel\vibration\VibrationPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

> Task :app:processProfileGoogleServices
Parsing json file: C:\Projects\Apps\app_name\android\app\google-services.json

> Task :app:processProfileManifest
C:\Projects\Apps\app_name\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-31:50 Warning:
        activity#com.google.firebase.auth.internal.FederatedSignInActivity@android:launchMode was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:24 to replace other declarations but no other declaration present

> Task :firebase_admob:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: C:\Users\riley\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_admob-0.9.0+7\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebaseadmob\AdRequestBuilderFactory.java uses or overrides a deprecated A
PI.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

> Task :in_app_purchase:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: C:\Users\riley\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\in_app_purchase-0.2.1+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\inapppurchase\InAppPurchasePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations
.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

> Task :url_launcher:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: C:\Users\riley\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\url_launcher-5.1.6\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\urllauncher\WebViewActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

> Task :vibration:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: C:\Users\riley\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\vibration-1.2.1\android\src\main\java\com\benjaminabel\vibration\VibrationPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

> Task :app:processReleaseGoogleServices
Parsing json file: C:\Projects\Apps\app_name\android\app\google-services.json

> Task :app:processReleaseManifest
C:\Projects\Apps\app_name\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-31:50 Warning:
        activity#com.google.firebase.auth.internal.FederatedSignInActivity@android:launchMode was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:24 to replace other declarations but no other declaration present
C:\Users\riley\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\jetified-play-services-ads-18.1.1.aar\6d23619f8b95b25f4464612252358ef0\jars\classes.jar: D8: Type `sun.misc.Unsafe` was not found, it is required for default
 or static interface methods desugaring of `void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdbf$zzi.<clinit>()`
C:\Users\riley\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-ads-base-18.1.1.aar\231d5d4dcfade07eb7a0be8b90002812\jars\classes.jar: D8: Type `libcore.io.Memory` was not found, it is required for default o
r static interface methods desugaring of `void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdta$zzc.zza(long, byte)`
C:\Users\riley\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-ads-base-18.1.1.aar\231d5d4dcfade07eb7a0be8b90002812\jars\classes.jar: D8: Type `libcore.io.Memory` was not found, it is required for default o
r static interface methods desugaring of `void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdta$zza.zza(long, byte)`

> Task :app:lint
Calling mockable JAR artifact transform to create file: C:\Users\riley\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\android.jar\7989af089b4a6324473ebc04dc57cffd\android.jar with input C:\Installations\AndroidSDK\platf
orms\android-29\android.jar
Calling mockable JAR artifact transform to create file: C:\Users\riley\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\android.jar\26ca7948663a2f90731d5c1d010b2880\android.jar with input C:\Installations\AndroidSDK\platf
orms\android-28\android.jar
Calling mockable JAR artifact transform to create file: C:\Users\riley\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\android.jar\338850fb4843944a0a1dcfccaa4cb553\android.jar with input C:\Installations\AndroidSDK\platf
orms\android-27\android.jar
Ran lint on variant debug: 5 issues found
Ran lint on variant profile: 5 issues found
Ran lint on variant release: 5 issues found
Wrote HTML report to file:///C:/Projects/Apps/app_name/android/build/app/reports/lint-results.html
Wrote XML report to file:///C:/Projects/Apps/app_name/android/build/app/reports/lint-results.xml

> Task :app_review:lint
Ran lint on variant debug: 1 issues found
Ran lint on variant profile: 1 issues found
Ran lint on variant release: 1 issues found
Wrote HTML report to file:///C:/Projects/Apps/app_name/android/build/app_review/reports/lint-results.html
Wrote XML report to file:///C:/Projects/Apps/app_name/android/build/app_review/reports/lint-results.xml

> Task :auto_orientation:lint
Ran lint on variant profile: 1 issues found
Ran lint on variant debug: 1 issues found
Ran lint on variant release: 1 issues found
Wrote HTML report to file:///C:/Projects/Apps/app_name/android/build/auto_orientation/reports/lint-results.html
Wrote XML report to file:///C:/Projects/Apps/app_name/android/build/auto_orientation/reports/lint-results.xml

> Task :firebase_admob:lint
Ran lint on variant release: 2 issues found
Ran lint on variant debug: 2 issues found
Ran lint on variant profile: 2 issues found
Wrote HTML report to file:///C:/Projects/Apps/app_name/android/build/firebase_admob/reports/lint-results.html
Wrote XML report to file:///C:/Projects/Apps/app_name/android/build/firebase_admob/reports/lint-results.xml

> Task :firebase_auth:lint
Ran lint on variant debug: 4 issues found
Ran lint on variant release: 4 issues found
Ran lint on variant profile: 4 issues found
Wrote HTML report to file:///C:/Projects/Apps/app_name/android/build/firebase_auth/reports/lint-results.html
Wrote XML report to file:///C:/Projects/Apps/app_name/android/build/firebase_auth/reports/lint-results.xml

> Task :firebase_core:lint
Ran lint on variant release: 3 issues found
Ran lint on variant profile: 3 issues found
Ran lint on variant debug: 3 issues found
Wrote HTML report to file:///C:/Projects/Apps/app_name/android/build/firebase_core/reports/lint-results.html
Wrote XML report to file:///C:/Projects/Apps/app_name/android/build/firebase_core/reports/lint-results.xml

> Task :firebase_dynamic_links:lint
Ran lint on variant profile: 4 issues found
Ran lint on variant release: 4 issues found
Ran lint on variant debug: 4 issues found
Wrote HTML report to file:///C:/Projects/Apps/app_name/android/build/firebase_dynamic_links/reports/lint-results.html
Wrote XML report to file:///C:/Projects/Apps/app_name/android/build/firebase_dynamic_links/reports/lint-results.xml

> Task :image_picker:lint
Ran lint on variant debug: 4 issues found
Ran lint on variant profile: 4 issues found
Ran lint on variant release: 4 issues found
Wrote HTML report to file:///C:/Projects/Apps/app_name/android/build/image_picker/reports/lint-results.html
Wrote XML report to file:///C:/Projects/Apps/app_name/android/build/image_picker/reports/lint-results.xml

> Task :in_app_purchase:lint
Ran lint on variant debug: 4 issues found
Ran lint on variant release: 4 issues found
Ran lint on variant profile: 4 issues found
Wrote HTML report to file:///C:/Projects/Apps/app_name/android/build/in_app_purchase/reports/lint-results.html
Wrote XML report to file:///C:/Projects/Apps/app_name/android/build/in_app_purchase/reports/lint-results.xml

> Transform byte-buddy-agent.jar (net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:1.8.0) with JetifyTransform
ERROR: [TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${version.junit}'
ERROR: [TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${version.mockito}'

> Transform byte-buddy.jar (net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.8.0) with JetifyTransform
ERROR: [TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${project.groupId}'
ERROR: [TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${project.version}'
ERROR: [TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${version.asm}'
ERROR: [TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${version.asm}'
ERROR: [TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${version.junit}'
ERROR: [TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${version.mockito}'
ERROR: [TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${version.asm}'
ERROR: [TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${version.asm}'
ERROR: [TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${project.groupId}'
ERROR: [TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${project.version}'

> Task :package_info:lint
Ran lint on variant debug: 1 issues found
Ran lint on variant profile: 1 issues found
Ran lint on variant release: 1 issues found
Wrote HTML report to file:///C:/Projects/Apps/app_name/android/build/package_info/reports/lint-results.html
Wrote XML report to file:///C:/Projects/Apps/app_name/android/build/package_info/reports/lint-results.xml

> Task :screen:lint
Ran lint on variant profile: 0 issues found
Ran lint on variant debug: 0 issues found
Ran lint on variant release: 0 issues found

> Task :shared_preferences:lint
Ran lint on variant release: 9 issues found
Ran lint on variant profile: 9 issues found
Ran lint on variant debug: 9 issues found
Wrote HTML report to file:///C:/Projects/Apps/app_name/android/build/shared_preferences/reports/lint-results.html
Wrote XML report to file:///C:/Projects/Apps/app_name/android/build/shared_preferences/reports/lint-results.xml

> Task :url_launcher:lint
Ran lint on variant release: 1 issues found
Ran lint on variant debug: 1 issues found
Ran lint on variant profile: 1 issues found
Wrote HTML report to file:///C:/Projects/Apps/app_name/android/build/url_launcher/reports/lint-results.html
Wrote XML report to file:///C:/Projects/Apps/app_name/android/build/url_launcher/reports/lint-results.xml

> Task :vibration:lint
Ran lint on variant release: 1 issues found
Ran lint on variant debug: 1 issues found
Ran lint on variant profile: 1 issues found
Wrote HTML report to file:///C:/Projects/Apps/app_name/android/build/vibration/reports/lint-results.html
Wrote XML report to file:///C:/Projects/Apps/app_name/android/build/vibration/reports/lint-results.xml

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 4m 47s
1044 actionable tasks: 679 executed, 365 up-to-date
```

EDIT3:

pubspec.yaml plugin list:

```
  cupertino_icons: 0.1.2
  firebase_admob: 0.9.0+7
  screen: 0.0.5
  image_picker: 0.6.1+4
  firebase_auth: 0.14.0+5
  shared_preferences: 0.5.3+4
  rflutter_alert: 1.0.3
  url_launcher: 5.1.6
  in_app_purchase: 0.2.1+4
  firebase_dynamic_links: 0.5.0+1
  app_review: 1.0.0
  auto_orientation: 1.0.5
  vibration: 1.2.1
```

I have been using these plugins for months without issue, but it could be something to do with the updates.

EDIT4:

Android Gradle sync failure:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebugArm'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.run(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.LocalTaskInfoExecutor.execute(LocalTaskInfoExecutor.java:42)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:277)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:262)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:135)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:200)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeWithWork(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:191)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'c:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:395)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecAction.execute(DefaultExecAction.java:37)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFileOperations.exec(DefaultFileOperations.java:232)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.exec(DefaultProject.java:1112)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.exec(DefaultProject.java:1107)
    at org.gradle.api.Project$exec$7.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:128)
    at BaseFlutterTask.buildBundle(c:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle:787)
    at BaseFlutterTask$buildBundle.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:157)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:161)
    at FlutterTask.build(c:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle:918)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:801)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:768)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:131)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:99)
    ... 34 more
```

Comment: sorry to hear that you are having issues with Flutter. have you tried this: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23777

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply mate.   I have read through that forum and it seems to be quite old (this is what I mean by flutter team not resolving any of these issues).   My flutter.gradle file appears to be correct by current standards, but this was a good find.

I am currently trying to work out the point at where the app really breaks (because the error message is useless).   If I make a brand new app, it runs fine.   I have tried copying over all my lib and settings files into the new app and it breaks again.   So I am just going to try going slow and see where the break is.

Comment: Have updated the question with all the latest tests I have performed.   Is anyone able to assist from this point?   It seems a fundamental flaw with the backend.

Comment: that is strange indeed... you have mentioned that you created a new app and copied the lib and setting files. what setting files are you referring to?

Comment: I copied over my build.gradle, pubspec.yaml etc etc into the new app and it broke.   I have then been going through with a brand new working vanilla app and trying to add plugins one by one and it is breaking.   If I am not able to add plugins to a base vanilla app then something is seriously broken.   Either its the plugins themselves, the flutter IDE or something to do with my environment.   I don't think it is my environment because everything works up to a point, and it breaks immediately when certain plugins are added, as you can see above.  Really struggling with this.

Comment: @Bisclavret I don't sure I would have sane answers, until you change the question. Could you please describe just last action and last error, with all the configuration from Gradle and Stacktrace.

Comment: Hi GensaGames, thank you so much for the reply.   It turns out I had no JavaSDK installed, so I set this up and have added the stacktrace as you requested.

Comment: please also add what types of plugins you are using in the pubspec.yaml... maybe we can find a clue there

Comment: Thanks digitaljoni, I have added my plugins list to the question.

Comment: Have you tried running android project (android folder of flutter project) in debug mode with breakpoints on exceptions to see where it crashes?

Comment: Hey Igor, tried to follow your suggestions, but when I run the android component of the app the sync actually fails.   Error log added to question above.

Comment: Maybe try upgrading firebase plugins?

Comment: Hi Igor, I have tried every version of the firebase_auth plugin and everyone of them is broken.  This is true even if I start a brand new application, just the vanilla default one with no plugins, and then try and add any version of firebase_auth, it all falls apart.

Comment: You tried switch between flutter versions/branches? Also take a look at this [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28909#issuecomment-469893767). It sounds similar

Comment: Hi guys, sorry I have been away a few days.   Been looking at this again and testing with a vanilla app.   I will post findings in the original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I basically had to rebuild my app, from scratch.  Updating flutter is an absolute nightmare, and I highly recommend against ever doing this until absolutely necessary.

The fix was to put the original app aside, reinstall everything from scratch to the latest versions.

Then try to add plugins one at a time, each time they fail, roll back a version and try again.   Eventually you will get down to the versions that actually work.

Once you can compile the empty app with the added plugins, start pasting in your old code a bit at a time, and rerunning.   You will be able to tackle individual errors as they arise this way.

Absolute nightmare of a platform, this.  But this method will sort you out.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are having problems with your build files.

You could try running `flutter clean`.

This may solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Was in the same hellish nightmare - solution in my case eventually was a plugin that was out of sync with the flutter engine. Example:

- Say you start off with Flutter 3.3.10
- Pull in a plugin in pubspec.yaml (in my case syncfusion) by specifiying:

  syncfusion_flutter_pdf:
- Let's assume the syncfusion version is 2.3.0.0 in this example
- You then upgrade to Flutter 3.7.0
- Perform flutter pub get at some point, and the plugin updates to 2.4.0.0
- Now when if you revert back to flutter 3.3.10 like I did, the plugin is at a too advanced version, and I needed to specify it explicitly as such:

  syncfusion_flutter_pdf: 2.3.0.0

After that things started working again

Answer (score -1):

Try to add firebase_core plugin it solve my problems with firebase plugins