# builder.attribute('href', _pdfFilePath) when I try to use syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer

Tags: flutter, pdf, syncfusion

I am coding a PDF on flutter using 'syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer' library. I tried everything but always I receive  the same error message:

[image]

Next code I'm trying

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer/pdfviewer.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'Syncfusion PDF Viewer Demo',
    home: HomePage(),
  ));
}

/// Represents Homepage for Navigation
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePage createState() => _HomePage();
}

class _HomePage extends State<HomePage> {
  final GlobalKey<SfPdfViewerState> _pdfViewerKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Syncfusion Flutter PDF Viewer'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.bookmark,
              color: Colors.white,
              semanticLabel: 'Bookmark',
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              _pdfViewerKey.currentState?.openBookmarkView();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: SfPdfViewer.network(
        'https://cdn.syncfusion.com/content/PDFViewer/flutter-succinctly.pdf',
        key: _pdfViewerKey,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are *not* open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and might affect downstream re-users of your code.

Comment: I've opened a new project and it runned. I have no idea what was the matter, but worked

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem and it turned out to be a mismatch between plugin version and flutter version. (I went back and forth to a new Flutter version).

Wrote a more detailed answer here: [Flutter completely broken after update (again)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58404092/flutter-completely-broken-after-update-again/75382160#75382160)

Also - the syncfusion support proved very useful for this